# Rails weird result with find and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can someone point me the reason for following:

```
JobType.find 17
#=> 
#<JobType id: 17, title: "some_title", description: "one description", reward: #    <BigDecimal:1009bbb48,'0.1E1',9(18)>, min_payout: 0.019999999552965164, min_skill_score: 0.6000000238418579, max_payout: 1.0, max_skill_score: 0.9300000071525574, difficulty_level: 2.0, variable_reward: true>
JobType.where(id: 17).first
#=>
#<JobType id: 17, title: "some_title", description: "one description", reward: #<BigDecimal:1009bbb48,'0.1E1',9(18)>, min_payout: 0.02, min_skill_score: 0.6, max_payout: 1.0, max_skill_score: 0.93 difficulty_level: 2.0, variable_reward: true>
```

In database, The values for min_payout is 0.6, max_skill_score is 0.93, but the find returns that weird long float.

SQL queries logged:

```
# find
JobType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `job_types`.* FROM `job_types` WHERE `job_types`.`id` = ? LIMIT [["id", 17]]

# where
JobType Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `job_types`.* FROM `job_types` WHERE `job_types`.`id` = 17
```

Why is find behaving like that.

I am using rails 3.2.13 and mysql gem.

Comment: I would bet it on floating point accuracy problem, I think it's preferred to store such values as you do in decimal type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: I understand that, but I have max_skill_score default to 0.93 and min_skill_score default to 0.6 in database, why different result?

Comment: Because this is float, and float is stored in binary format. And some decimal values are hard to represent in binary, etc. Use decimal.

Comment: yes ok, lets agree that it is floating point accuracy problem, but my question is why only find method return weird values, whereas where never returns those long value.

Comment: what is puzzling me is SQL statement you printed: `JobType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT job_types.* FROM job_types WHERE job_types.id = ? LIMIT [["id", 17]]`. I get different query when I run `Model.find ID`. are you using up to date rails 3.2? i dont get any `?` in my query.

Comment: try rails 3.2.12 and see if you get same result.

Comment: @roxxypoxxy, I feel you might be missing the good advice you're being given. Unless you need the flexibility of a floating point number, you ought to be using a decimal.

Comment: I used 3.2.12 also,same result, For now I will use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the use floating point numbers. Floating point numbers involve a binary representation, in which some numbers that can be exactly represented in decimal notation easily are not stored exactly.

For example, `0.6` in decimal is (approximately) `0.111111000110011001100110011010` in binary. When converted back to decimal this number is (approximately) `0.6000000238418579`.

Due to this, when you store `0.6` in a float column, the value returned to you will be (slightly) different. The exact value you receive depends on the **specific handling** that the value has gone through, which may differ depending on a variety of factors.

In order to avoid this, you would be better off using a `BigDecimal`, and setting the storage type on that column to `:decimal`.

Comment: You mean to there is difference between how object is created by find and where + first. That may be the case, because only find return that long values.